# connect localhost on pc to github

Tags: linux, github, xampp

I have my own project hosted on the github. I am using `Xampp` server on my local machine with necessary database and tables regarding my project.

How can I connect or replica my localhost to GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty unclear, but if I understand this correctly, you wish to use github as an hosting service. Short answer is that you can't.

If you want to publish your project, you'll need a server and a domain name.

If your project is a static website, then you can use [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) to host it.